How is the "small flush" vertical lever connected?
I have a Geberit AquaClean WC system (sorry for the possible ridiculous wording in this question - I am not a native speaker of English, so the technical terms will be, at best, funny, and at worst, a mystery (let me know if it is unclear!)). It consists of a seat, a construction, and a mechanism to flush the water. There is a "big flush" button (this one works) and a "small flush" one (which stopped to work)
My problem: the "small flush" part does not flush and loosely moves vertically.
This is how it looks like when I remove the front plates. The rods are pushed into the loops of the vertical things that ultimately close the hole at the bottom of the reservoir. This is what is expected after point nr 3 in the PDF with mounting instructions

A closer look from the top of the mechanism (sorry, I could not focus on the important part (which is blurred). Fortunately it is big enough to be readable)

This is what it looks like when I press on the right rod (this is the "fully pressed" position with my finger pushing the rod)

After releasing the rod, this is how the rod + blue loop are:

What is happening is that the blue vertical loop (this is the top of the vertical mechanism/column that closes the water exit hole at the bottom) stays like this.

it does not flush the water
and (or rather: therefore) it is not pushed down

I suppose the column has somehow disconnected from something further down and is now useless.
My question: how is it attached? If it fell off, is there a way to reattach it without removing the whole wall?
